# Android - CSS Buttons to XML

Tags: android, css, xml

I'm new to programming in Android.
I found a set of custom buttons in CSS, and I was wondering if it was possible to pass it to XML themes/styles/custom_button (I never programmed in CSS).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Android layouts are created **solely** in XML and cannot be created by directly transforming CSS code.

Any CSS button layouts you find that you wish to use must be replicated though the use of XML styles and views in Android.

For more on styling and themes in Android, I suggest checking out the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)